# How to filter Tooltip in Leaflet map?

Tags: text, filter, leaflet

I have a file with serial numbers from 100 to 999. With this file I want to filter out three numbers to display on a map. I have been able to filter both polygons and circle markers but for Tooltips I have not succeeded. This is the code I've been using, how should I fix this?

```
var po_txt = new L.layerGroup();
$.getJSON("../data/po_txt.geojson", function(json) {

var pointLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){

// Filter file
if (feature.properties.Po > 125 && feature.properties.Po < 128 || feature.properties.Po === 129  ) return true

// .bindTooltip can't use straight 'feature.properties.attribute'

label = String(feature.properties.Po) 
return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
radius: 0,
}).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my1-labels"}).openTooltip();
}
});
pointLayer.addData(json)
pointLayer.addTo(po_txt);

})
```

I did manage to fix this, needed to put in a function for filter and below code made it work...

```
var po_txt = new L.layerGroup();
$.getJSON("../data/po_txt.geojson", function(json) {

// Filter
function po_filt (feature){
if (feature.properties.Po > 125 && feature.properties.Po < 128 || feature.properties.Po === 129 ) return true
}
var pointLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
filter: po_filt,
pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
label = String(feature.properties.Po) // .bindTooltip can't use straight 'feature.properties.attribute'
return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
  radius: 0,
}).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my1-labels"}).openTooltip();
}
});
pointLayer.addData(json)
pointLayer.addTo(po_txt);

})
```

Comment: Hi, if you managed to solve your issue, you should describe it as an _answer_ and later on _accept_ it, instead of writing the solution in your question. That way people know your issue is fixed.

Comment: Yes I managed to solve the problem using filter function... thanks